# Select statement with multiple rows from condition on values in single column

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements

I have the table below.Using salary as condition I want to get multiple rows. 
Below is current table call it employee.

```
    empid     name         salary
-----------------------------------
1   A1        alex        20000
2   B2        ben         4500
3   C1        carl        14000
```

compare the salary to certain fixed values, and every time the salary is larger than the fixed value, show a record in output.My attempt condition case is close to this:

```
   incometype= case When salary<6000 then 101 When salary Between 6000 And 18000 Then
   102 Else 103 End
```

Desired ouput would be:

```
     empid     name   salary  incometype
------------------------------------------
1   A1        alex    20000    101
2   A1        alex    20000    102
3   A!        alex    20000    103
4   B2        ben     4500     101
5   C1        carl    14000    101
6   C1        carl    14000    102
```

I have tried using union but union will give me 3 rows for each record even when value meets 1st condition.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 1 to 1 mapped to your input? Why do you want to return 6 rows for 3 input rows?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I need them like that for taxtion bracket range.Long story short my ideal output needs to be as above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear, because your logic implies that you should only have 3 output rows for 3 input rows. Your output however implies that you want to compare the salary to certain fixed values, and every time the salary is larger than the fixed value, show a record in output.

If the former is the case, Minh's query is all you need. In the latter case, you can do something like this:

```
select e.*, m.incometype
from employee e
left join 
( 
 select 0 as threshold, 101 as incometype
 union
 select 5999 as threshold, 102 as incometype
 union
 select 17999 as threshold, 103 as incometype
) m
on e.salary > m.threshold
order by e.empid
```

If you want to add a calculate column i.e. one with values calculated using columns in this query, you can simply add it as a column in the `select` clause, like so:

```
select e.*, 
m.incometype, 
case 
when <first condition> then <business logic here>
....
else <handle default case>
end as yourcomputedcolumn
from
...
```

Comment: I offered that condition for explanation purpose as I could not establish proper logic your solution above might do the trick.My query is much larger and complex so I tuned down to the aspect that I can get quick assistance without overload.Thanks

Comment: Fair enough. Let me know if my solution works for you. BTW which RDBMS are you using, although mine uses standard operations only.

Comment: what if i need to add another column tax still based on grosspay where for type 101 tax=0.6 *grosspay,102 tax=0.6 *(grosspay-6000),103 tax =0

Comment: I suggest you add this as a separate question for better visibility. In a nutshell however, once you have the columns, you can just add a calculated column to the query.

Comment: can you initiate chat am sure its something minor I just dont know how to add it in the query

Comment: the problem is if I do so using the case it will just give me one definite value eg tax for 20000 will give only the default 0 for row with 101,102 and 103 instead of assigning the tax at 101 and at  102 and 103 @shree.pat18

Comment: add the following before `from` to the code above: 
 `case when m.incometype <= 101 then 0.6 * e.salary when m.incometype <= 102 then 0.6 * (e.salary - 6000) else 0 end as tax`

Answer (score 1):

This returns 3 rows and enough for your need:

```
  SELECT empid, name, salary, 
    case When salary<6000 then 101 
         When salary Between 6000 And 18000 Then 102 
         Else 103 End as incometype
    FROM employee;
```

Comment: that will give me just a single output not ideal for my need.For example 14000 will not appear in two rows one with 101 another 102

Comment: well your right according to above query but ideally it should be taxed on 101 and 102.

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear on the requirement, however the following worked for me:

```
Select 
    EmpId,Name,Sal,101 IncomeType
from Emp
Union all
Select 
    EmpId,Name,Sal,102
from Emp
Where Sal > 6000
union all
Select 
    EmpId,Name,Sal,103
from Emp
Where Sal > 18000;
```

Comment: that was my initial trial however that will give 3 rows every tym see @shree's solution.Thats what I needed.thanks though.

Comment: I don't think so.Please note that I have filtered the records based on a different set of conditions. Only the first select returns all the rows from the table.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that actually this looks like it should work too.let me try it plus I need to addd another column tax where if salary <6000 tax=0.06*salary,else if salary between 6000 and 18001 then tax=0.06*(salary-6000) else tax=0

Comment: This should do it:

Select EmpId,Name,Sal,IncomeType,Case IncomeType When 101 then 0.6 * Sal WHEN 102 then 0.6 *(Sal-6000) Else 0 End as Tax
From (Select 
    EmpId,Name,Sal,101 IncomeType
from Emp
Union all
Select 
    EmpId,Name,Sal,102
from Emp
Where Sal > 6000
union all
Select 
    EmpId,Name,Sal,103
from Emp
Where Sal > 18000);