# Select statement with multiple rows from condition on values in single column affecting more than one column

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I have the table below.Using salary as condition I want to get multiple rows. Below is current table call it employee.

```
   empid |    name    |     salary
-----------------------------------
1   A1        alex        20000
2   B2        ben         4500
3   C1        carl        14000
```

compare the salary to certain fixed values, and every time the salary is larger than the fixed value, show a record in output.Also output a calculated tax column.Below is a step closer to my final result

```
select e.*,tax= (case when salary<6000 then tax=0.06 *salary,when salary between 6000 and 18000 then tax= 0.06 *(salary -6000),else tax =0 ),m.incometype,
from employee e
left join 
( 
 select 0 as threshold, 101 as incometype
 union
 select 5999 as threshold, 102 as incometype
 union
 select 17999 as threshold, 103 as incometype
) m
on e.salary > m.threshold
order by e.empid
```

Desired ouput would be:

```
   empid |    name |  salary | incometype | tax
----------------------------------------------
1   A1        alex    20000    101       360
2   A1        alex    20000    102       720 
3   A!        alex    20000    103       0 
4   B2        ben     4500     101       270
5   C1        carl    14000    101       360
6   C1        carl    14000    102       480
```

this is a question further to [Select statement with multiple rows from condition on values in single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300423/select-statement-with-multiple-rows-from-condition-on-values-in-single-column/)

Comment: what is the last condition in the case "103"?

Comment: The first output rows suggests that you want 0.06 * 6000, not 0.06 * `salary`. Please clarify, in words if necessary, what you expect.

Comment: 0.06* salary which will be less than 6000 @shree.pat18

Comment: 103 takes default value 0 once rest are exhausted @ashok_p

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
select e.*,
case 
when salary<6000 then (0.06*salary) 
when salary between 6000 and 1800 then (0.06*(salary -6000))
when m.incometype=103 then 0 
end as tax
,m.incometype,
from employee e
left join 
( 
 select 0 as threshold, 101 as incometype
 union
 select 5999 as threshold, 102 as incometype
 union
 select 17999 as threshold, 103 as incometype
) m
on e.salary > m.threshold
order by e.empid
```

Comment: I think my case would need to be applied as a left join like the incometype so it appears in 3 rows lyk the incometype